# Is there a way to stop scrolling programmatically after the dragging started in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll

What I need is basically to stop scrolling at a certain time without rebuilding/setting the state of the scrollable widget.

I know I can disable scrolling by using a boolean variable and setting state to switch between `ScrollablePhysics` like following as many people suggested:

```
physics: _canScroll ? ScrollPhysics() : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

However, I don't want to call `setState()` and rebuild the children of the scrollable widget.

Comment: create your own, custom `ScrollPhysics` class and implement both physics behaviors in it - but actually calling `setState` shouldn't be much problem, why dont you want to do that?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I don't want to use `setState` because the children of the scrollable widget have some complicated animations and asynchronous behavior.

Comment: it does not matter: if the code for those anims and asyncs is initiated inside children's  `initState` method

Comment: But when I set parent's state, child widgets are being destroyed and their `initState` is called again. I want them to preserve their state.

Comment: Thank you for your helps, looks like my widgets were recreating because I create a new `GlobalKey` for their parents when rebuilding. Now I can use `setState` without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the physics without calling `setState()` because the UI has to update after changing the physics. If rebuilding those widgets are too cpu intensive for your case then consider using `ListView.builder()` or adding `cacheExtent`

Comment: I am already using `ListView.builder()`. The reason I don't want to call `setState` is not because those widgets are intensive, it's because they have animations and asynchronous function calls.

Comment: As pskink points out, "it does not matter: if the code for those anims and asyncs is initiated inside children's initState method".